# Как скачать картинку по URL и выводить оффлайн?

Tags: android

У меня есть база данных. Есть URL по которым лежат картинки. Мне нужно их сохранить куда-то и занести в базу её местонахождение для последующего вывода. Как скачать картинку? Как занести её в базу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Загрузите изображение через https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, после загрузки сохраните в SQLite ссылку. Для работы с базой рекомендую использовать библиотеку ORMLite.
2. Когда Вам понадобится показать офлайн картинку, используйте все тот же `Universal-Image-Loader` только уже вместе URL укажите локальную ссылку на SD.

Это вам сэкономит кучу времени и убережет от ООМ при правильном использовании библиотеки.

**UPD**
Не большой пример для работы с UIL

добавляем либу

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

инициализируем библиотеку

```
Executor downloadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int memClass = am.getMemoryClass();
        final int memoryCacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .taskExecutor(downloadExecutor)
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize)) // 2 Mb
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(this, 5 * 1000, 30 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (30 s)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

и в нужном месте качаем и записываем в файл

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage("http://www.podstavka.com/images/products/nakleyka-ostorojno-chaynik-.jpg", new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                File imageFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AndroidTest/data/"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Image");
                if (! imageFileDir.exists()){
                    if (! imageFileDir.mkdirs()){
                        Log.d("TAG", "уупс");
                    }
                }
                File mediaFile = new File(imageFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + "myImage.jpg");

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
                    loadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Естественно вам нужно дополнить код

1. Правильное имя файла
2. Сохранение в базу путь к файлу
3. в AndroidManifest.xml добавьте разрешения `android.permission.INTERNET` и  `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Когда нужно будет поместить картинку офлайн вызовите `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("Путь к файлу из базы", @ImageView)`

Comment: Не получается у меня подружиться с библиотекой

Comment: какой из 2х именно?

Comment: С UIL. Я еще перепутал Picasso с ней. А для базы зачем использовать библиотеку? Вроде итак все понятно.

Comment: дополнил небольшим примером

Comment: Крашится не из-за этого

Comment: скиньте стек сюда

Comment: Да не дают вставить. Может Permission каких нет?

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET и android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Эти permission есть.

Comment: Без стека ничем не могу помочь, это весь код, я также создал проект с нуля. и это все, что там есть

Comment: А где файл должен появиться? У меня его нет.

Comment: на SD карте, /AndroidTest/data/"+ appName + "/Image/myImage.jpg"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36429/discussion-between-chaynik-and--).

Comment: хм Фотография есть.

Answer (score 4):

Создаете папку на SD -> сохраняете вашу картинку.

Во время парсинга картинки по URL вы скорей всего используете BitmapFactory, для её декодирования. Следовательно можете создать таблицу в БД, в которой будете хранить путь картинки, где на SD лежит ваш файл. Примерно так:

```
public Bitmap createBitMap(String path){
File file = new File(path);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: А если на телефоне нет SD ?

Comment: Всё тоже самое, я как пример дала. метод будет получать путь только с памяти телефона, разницы нет.

Comment: Сейчас попробую.